# How to get CATPart number and name into text editor in drawing using macro?

Tags: vba, drawing, fill, catia

I'm trying to create a macro in CATIA. The macro should use a UserForm with the button. After clicking on the button, it will automatically fill in the text field with data (Part Name + Part Number).

I am a total novice in VBA.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim DrwDocument As DrawingDocument
    Set DrwDocument = CATIA.ActiveDocument

    Set DrwSheets = DrwDocument.Sheets
    Set Selection = DrwDocument.Selection
    Set DrwSheet = DrwSheets.ActiveSheet
    Set DrwView = DrwSheet.Views.ActiveView
    Set DrwTexts = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Sheets.ActiveSheet.Views.ActiveView.Texts

    Dim parameters4 As Parameters
    Set parameters4 = DrwDocument.Parameters

    Dim realParam4 As Parameter
    Set realParam4 = parameters4.Item("Sheet.1\ViewMakeUp.3\Scale")
    
    DrwView.Activate
    Set Projekt = DrwTexts.Add(tbProjekt.Text, (288), (45.5))
    Projekt.AnchorPosition = catMiddleLeft
    Projekt.SetFontName 0, 0, "Monospac821 BT"
    Projekt.SetFontSize 0, 0, 3
        
    Set PocetKs = DrwTexts.Add(tbPocetKs.Text + "x", (36), (78))
    PocetKs.AnchorPosition = catMiddleLeft
    PocetKs.SetFontName 0, 0, "Monospac821 BT"
    PocetKs.SetFontSize 0, 0, 3
        
    If OptionZrk = True Then
        Set PocetKsZrk = DrwTexts.Add(tbPocetKs.Text + "x", (36),(70))
        PocetKsZrk.AnchorPosition = catMiddleLeft
        PocetKsZrk.SetFontName 0, 0, "Monospac821 BT"
        PocetKsZrk.SetFontSize 0, 0, 3
                
        Set ZrkText = DrwTexts.Add("Zrkadlový", (102), (80))
        ZrkText.AnchorPosition = catMiddleLeft
        ZrkText.SetFontName 0, 0, "Monospac821 BT"
        ZrkText.SetFontSize 0, 0, 3
    End If
     
    Set Material = DrwTexts.Add(cbMaterial.Text, (288), (37.5))
    Material.AnchorPosition = catMiddleLeft
    Material.SetFontName 0, 0, "Monospac821 BT"
    Material.SetFontSize 0, 0, 3
        
    Set Mierka = DrwTexts.Add(realParam4.ValueAsString, (238), (40))
    Mierka.AnchorPosition = catMiddleLeft
    Mierka.SetFontName 0, 0, "Monospac821 BT"
    Mierka.SetFontSize 0, 0, 3
        
    Set DatumUpravy = DrwTexts.Add(tbDatum.Text, (355), (38))
    DatumUpravy.AnchorPosition = catMiddleLeft
    DatumUpravy.SetFontName 0, 0, "Monospac821 BT"
    DatumUpravy.SetFontSize 0, 0, 3
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? The sub _CATLinks_ of the _Drawing_Titleblock_PlyBook.CATScript_ in the catia installation folder shows how that could work.

Comment: I have created my own title block, but without any links ... I need (as part of training / education) to make links using macros.
At this point, I was able to pull the view scale out of the parameters. I don't see the parameter anywhere - PartName + PartNumber ---- maybe I'm blind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via the *GenerativeBehavior* of a view you get the shown product.

```vb
dim oProduct as Product
Set oProduct = DrwView.GenerativeBehavior.Document

MsgBox CStr(oProduct.PartNumber)
MsgBox CStr(oProduct.Nomenclature)
```

Make shure that the view has a link to a geometry/product

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added the code to my program. After testing, it gives an error - Run-time error "424" Object required

Comment: In which line? I just corrected a typo in my code.

Comment: typo was not a problem, I noticed the missing letter. Error 424 is in the line: Set oProduct = DrwView.GenerativeBehavior.Document

Comment: Please use the watch function to check if the DrwView is set and has a link to the 3d geometry

Comment: as I mentioned, I am a novice. Watch function mean breakpoint? If so, I put a breakpoint at the beginning of the program in the line: Set DrwDocument = CATIA.ActiveDocument. Using SHIFT + F8, I moved the code to the problem line: Set oProduct = DrwView.GenerativeBehavior.Document. As far as links are concerned, checking the Links of document table looks fine - STATUS LINK OK (i see linked part)

Comment: Please have a look on the functions of the VBA editor. e.g. http://www.fmsinc.com/TPapers/vbacode/Debug.asp#DebuggingViews